# PHP XML Parsing Problem with single node - inconsistence

Tags: php, xml, parsing

i want to parse xml files.
Its for an importer, where you can define a configuration

My Problem is, that the xml parser (SimpleXml & Dom) did it inconstistence.

When i only have one child node - it will give me a simpleXML

```
<sizes>
    <size>
        <gpp>   5,00</gpp>
        <gppcurrency>EUR</gppcurrency>
        <npp>   5,00</npp>
        <nppcurrency>EUR</nppcurrency>
        <sp>   5,00</sp>
        <spcurrency>EUR</spcurrency>
        <stock>100</stock>
    </size>
</sizes>
```

Will be

```
sizes [SimpleXmlElement]
 => size [SimpleXmlElement]
    - gpp
    - gppcurrency 
    ...
```

BUT if i have multiple nodes

```
<sizes>
    <size>
        <gpp>   5,00</gpp>
        <gppcurrency>EUR</gppcurrency>
        <npp>   5,00</npp>
        <nppcurrency>EUR</nppcurrency>
        <sp>   5,00</sp>
        <spcurrency>EUR</spcurrency>
        <stock>100</stock>
    </size>
    <size>
        <gpp>   5,00</gpp>
        <gppcurrency>EUR</gppcurrency>
        <npp>   5,00</npp>
        <nppcurrency>EUR</nppcurrency>
        <sp>   5,00</sp>
        <spcurrency>EUR</spcurrency>
        <stock>100</stock>
    </size>
</sizes>
```

It will output

```
sizes [SimpleXmlElement]
 => size array
   [0] [SimpleXmlElement]
      - gpp
      - gppcurrency 
      ...
   [1] [SimpleXmlElement]
      - gpp
      - gppcurrency 
      ...
```

This is realy incosistent and may you can help me find an answer for this.
Thanks

Comment: The first one is one element you see it's type of SimpleXmlElement::class. The other one is an array. Just check with `is_array()` and you know how handle it,

Comment: hi Markus Zeller, its not that easy.
as i said i have a generic importer.
So there can be any structured xml.

Comment: Hmm.. you just say, it would be inconstent, which is definetely not. Either you have a single element or an array of elements. What do you mean with "generic importer"? Alter the source to handle that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found my solution to consistencly get an array.

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace src\ImExport\Formatter;

use SimpleXMLElement;

class XmlToArrayFormatter
{
    public function parseXmlToArray(SimpleXmlElement $xml, $collection = [])
    {
        $childNodes = $xml->children();

        if (0 === $childNodes->count()) {
            if (empty($xml)) {
                return false;
            }

            return strval($xml);
        }
        $currentNodeAsArray = false;
        if ($this->getNodeLevel($xml) > 0 &&
            $this->hasOnlySubNodes($xml) &&
            !is_string($xml)) {
            $currentNodeAsArray = true;
        }

        foreach ($childNodes as $nodeName => $nodeValue) {
            $xmlArray = $this->parseXmlToArray($nodeValue);
            if ($currentNodeAsArray) {
                $collection[$nodeName][] = $xmlArray;
            } else {
                if ($xmlArray !== false) {
                    $collection[$nodeName] = $xmlArray;
                }
            }
        }

        return $collection;
    }

    protected function getNodeLevel(?SimpleXMLElement $parentNodes, $level = 0): int
    {
        if (is_null($parentNodes)) {
            return $level;
        }

        if (count($parentNodes->children())) {
            $level++;
        }

        foreach ($parentNodes->children() as $parentNodeValues) {
            $level = $this->getNodeLevel($parentNodeValues, $level);
        }

        return $level;
    }

    public function hasOnlySubNodes(?SimpleXMLElement $node): bool
    {
        foreach ($node->children() as $nodeValues) {
            if (count($nodeValues->children()) == 0 && !empty(strval($nodeValues))) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whether or not the internal pieces use an array does not matter. What is being returned is a `SimpleXMLElement` object (not a bare array) with getters that will return an iterable value in either case. The array you are seeing is how the value is stored within the `SimpleXMLElement`, but it will handle converting a single child item to an iterable value when you access it.

```php
foreach($singleNode->size as $size) {
    var_dump($size);
}
// object(SimpleXMLElement) { ["gpp"] ... }
```

```php
foreach($multiNode->size as $size) {
    var_dump($size);
}
// object(SimpleXMLElement) { ["gpp"] ... }
// object(SimpleXMLElement) { ["gpp"] ... }
```